# Script Dump mongodb

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodump

I've this script

```
for col in "${COLLECTIONS[@]}";
do
    mongodump --gzip --db $db --collection $col --query $QUERY --archive=/tmp/bkpmongodev/$db-$col-$FOLDER.gz
done
```

and when i run it, i get this error:

> positional arguments not allowed: [_id : { $gt : ObjectId("61b1eca70000000000000000") }}']

and when i do echo the command and i past it in terminal, it work

> echo "mongodump --gzip --db $db --collection $col --query $QUERY --archive=/tmp/bkpmongodev/$db-$col-$FOLDER.gz"

Comment: Try `mongodump --gzip --db=$db --collection=$col --query=$QUERY --archive=/tmp/bkpmongodev/$db-$col-$FOLDER.gz` or maybe you need `--query="$QUERY"`

Comment: the first did the same and the second shows up "Failed: query is not in proper format"

Comment: almost the same happen with mongoexport, showing "too many positional arguments: [{ "_id" : { "$gt" :  ObjectId("61b1eca70000000000000000") }}']"  in script, but when i do echo and past in terminal, the cmd works

Comment: I think it is a quoting problem. Maybe try `--query="'"$QUERY"'"` or similar. Do you have an example of printed command?

Comment: yes, follow the exemple:
mongodump --db=pedidoentregaDev --collection=registroRastreioCorreios --query=' { "_id" : { "$gt" : ObjectId("61b2346a0000000000000000") } } ' --archive=/tmp/bkpmongodev/2021-12-16-pedidoentregaDev-registroRastreioCorreios.gz --gzip

Answer (score 0):

the error occurred because of spaces between strings in $QUERY

Before:

```
QUERY=" { \"_id\" : { \"\$gt\" : ObjectId(\"$stringObjectId\") } } "
```

Now:

```
QUERY="{_id:{\$gt:ObjectId(\"$stringObjectId\")}}"
```